# Numpy Newaxis not working on datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

given a df

```
        article_id                     publish_time
0        1.3887168 2017-02-27 14:32:44.933000+00:00
1        1.8492707 2020-02-04 04:26:37.466000+00:00
2        1.6577063 2018-10-22 13:16:11.421000+00:00
3        1.8353042 2020-01-04 18:16:42.443000+00:00
4        1.7168334 2019-04-26 11:44:24.095000+00:00
           ...                              ...
1706487  1.7106429 2019-04-09 18:00:00.075000+00:00
1706488  1.6203404 2018-06-25 18:00:00.457000+00:00
1706489  1.8616276 2020-03-02 13:07:47.651000+00:00
1706490  1.6602395 2018-10-29 19:00:00.836000+00:00
1706491  1.2136582        2013-10-09 11:43:00+00:00
```

and matrix of int(the values are the df index)

```
labels
array([[      0,    2352,    1264, ...,    2670, 1381528,     146],
       [      1,    2829,    2356, ...,    2422,    1829,    2677],
       [      2,     971,    2531, ...,  786709,   13681, 1275732],
       ...,
       [1706489,  877935,  778557, ..., 1201173,  928024,  542028],
       [1319243, 1115890,  612037, ..., 1602534, 1320344,  948664],
       [1706491, 1003307,  896565, ..., 1114321,  877759, 1230176]],
      dtype=uint64)
```

I have to get the article_id for every value in the labels matrix

while this command working well

```
neighbors=pd.DataFrame(indexed_articles.article_id[:,None][labels[:,1:]].reshape(labels.shape[0],labels.shape[1]-1))
neighbors
        article_id          0          1  ...         16         17         18
0           1.7960     1.7102     1.6599  ...     1.8540  1.1186736     1.6420
1           1.7953     1.9508     1.7134  ...     1.7467    1.10013     1.8558
2           1.8316     1.5217     1.8062  ...   1.803242    1.25236  1.1320521
3           1.8300  1.1237499     1.6612  ...   1.353047   1.342191  1.1078822
4           1.8289     1.5450     1.5785  ...     1.5795   1.780752     1.8449
           ...        ...        ...  ...        ...        ...        ...
1706487  1.2017169   1.947293  1.1393375  ...   1.905496   1.846603  1.1197204
1706488  1.7609079  1.1262460  1.1108378  ...  1.1018603  1.1231691  1.1212798
1706489  1.2068534   1.898506   1.795085  ...  1.1415202   1.949853   1.572819
1706490  1.2069476  1.1110201  1.1712569  ...  1.3944061  1.1364608   1.970484
1706491  1.4533194  1.1507443   1.917284  ...  1.1108378   1.898048  1.1445274
```

if i run it on the datetime column -> publish_time

```
dates_df = pd.DataFrame(indexed_articles.publish_time[:,np.newaxis][labels[:,1:]].reshape(labels.shape[0],labels.shape[1]-1))
```

i got an index error

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: Your command works fine on my system on a small sample. Is your publish_time type a datetime?

Comment: @Ehsan -  1   publish_time          datetime64[ns, UTC]